# Came across these both methods in java which I find confusing. Can someone explain this?

Tags: java

I'm pretty much new to Java. I came across these two methods -

```
**Method -1** 
private Response callABC(StringRequest request) {
        return callABC(new StringRequest[] {request}).get(0);
    }
```

```
**Method -2**
private List<Response> callABC(StringRequest[] stringRequests) {
.....
}
```

Can someone please take time in explain me this code. From what I've understood - StringRequest[] creates request object. But request is also a parameter in method -1. How can it be both?

Comment: `new StringRequest[] {request}` creates an array of `StringRequest` with `request` as the sole element.

Comment: "StringRequest[] creates request Object". No, it creates nothing. It merely determines what type of parameter can be passed to it. -- new StringRequest[]{request} creates an object of type Array of StringRequests with sole element the String passed to that method as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Method 2 requires that your input is an array of `StringRequest` objects, and it gives you a `List` of `Response` objects for your output.

Method 1 requires that your input is a single `StringRequest` object, and you get just a single `Response` for your output.  But it achieves that by

- packaging up the `StringRequest` input into an array with just one element,
- calling method 2,
- unpacking the response, which presumably would be a `List` with just one element.

And it's OK for these two methods to have the same name.  The compiler can work out which one you want to call, based on whether you're passing in a single object, or an array.